# Программа вместо строк выводит кортежи

Tags: python, парсер, url, urllib

Изначально задача стоит такая:

1. Сверка ссылок по домену(*) из TXT №2 с TXT №1
2. Сохранение уникальны ссылок в отдельный TXT №3
3. Добавление уникальных ссылок в TXT №1

При сверке по доменам - идет сверка только доменов сайта без: http:// и без https:// , так же при сверке по домену не учитывается все что после доменной зоны (.com , .ru , и т.п.)

Программа работает стабильно хорошо и выводит строки, если входные данные стандартизированы и представляют из себя это:

Входные данные:

```
1.txt

http://site.com/
https://sit1e.com/vwdsvdfw/vwdefei/userpanel?cid=2
https://site.com/index.php?id=1
http://sit2e.com/
http://site.com/vwifow/fwviiwf?

2.txt

http://site.com/
https://sit1e213.com/vwdsvdfw/vwdefei/userpanel?cid=2
https://site.com/index.php?id=1
http://sit222e.com/
http://site.com/vwifow/fwviiwf?
```

Код программы:

```
import urllib.parse

def get_domains(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return ['.'.join(urllib.parse.urlparse(line.strip()).netloc.split('.')[:-1])
                for line in f]

dom1 = get_domains(r'1.txt')
dom2 = get_domains(r'2.txt')

doms = set(dom1) ^ set(dom2)

import re

def search_domains(filename, doms):
    with open(filename) as f:
        text = f.read()
    pat = r'(https?://[^./\r\n]*?\b(?:{})\b[^\r\n]*)'.format('|'.join(doms))
    return re.findall(pat, text)

outin13 = search_domains(r'2.txt', doms)

with open ('1.txt', 'a') as result:
    for i in outin13:
        result.write('\n' + i)
with open ('3.txt', 'w') as result:
    for i in outin13:
        result.write(i + '\n')

input('Нажмите Enter, чтобы завершить программу')
```

Результат работы программы:

```
1.txt

http://site.com/
https://sit1e.com/vwdsvdfw/vwdefei/userpanel?cid=2
https://site.com/index.php?id=1
http://sit2e.com/
http://site.com/vwifow/fwviiwf?
https://sit1e213.com/vwdsvdfw/vwdefei/userpanel?cid=2
http://sit222e.com/

3.txt

https://sit1e213.com/vwdsvdfw/vwdefei/userpanel?cid=2
http://sit222e.com/
```

Когда же программу решили проверить на реальных строчках, она выдала ошибку:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str
```

И я начал выводить в документы таким образом:

```
with open ('1.txt', 'a') as file:
    print(sep='\n', *outin13, file=file)

with open ('3.txt', 'w') as file:
    print(*outin13, file=file, sep='\n')
```

Пример выходных данных в виде кортежей:

```
3.txt

('http://site254.com/product-detail.php?pid=86   ', '')
('http://www.site345.com/seatrip07/place.php?tid=2   ', '')
('http://site1234.hr/moto-grip/index.php?m=135   ', '')
```

Как сделать так, чтобы выводились строчки, а не кортежи?
P.S. Пытался найти такие строчки, которые бы ломали программу и заставляли ее выводить кортежи, но идея не увенчалась успехом и найти какой-то определенный тип строчек не удалось.

Comment: можете привести в вопросе данные, которые позволят воспроизвести проблему с кортежами?

Comment: В какой строчке ошибка? Или лучше просто приведите весь текст ошибки целиком.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Web/Python/v10.py", line 25, in <module>
    result.write('\n' + i)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В реальных строках скорее всего иногда встречается запятая после адреса. Например:

http://site254.com/product-detail.php?pid=86,

Это и создает кортеж.

Для исправления поменяйте строки

```
for i in outin13:
    result.write('\n' + i)
```

на:

```
for i in outin13:
    if type(i) is tuple:
        result.write('\n' + i[0])
    else:
        result.write('\n' + i)
```

Comment: Использовал ваш код - работает как надо, спасибо!

Comment: @Ian. Раз код работает, поставьте птичку, что ответ принят. Человеку начислятся поощрительные баллы, а остальным будет видно, что помощь уже оказана.

Comment: Поискал в интернетах, ответ на свой вопрос и оказалось, что метод re.findall возвращает кортеж, если используются группирующие скобки в регулярном выражении, поэтому нужно через цикл доставать нулевой элемент кортежа.
Выводит кортеж такого вида ('То, что совпало с регулярным выражением','то, что не совпало')
Вторая часть всегда была пустой, что говорит о правильности метода, просто нужно по особому выводить.

Comment: @lan Спасибо, тоже буду знать.